# Approximations in Stochastic Differential Equations

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-approximation

Given a general SDE:   $dX_t=b(X_t,t)dt+\sigma (X_t,t)dB_t$ , $X_0 =x$  and a solution $X^x_t$, where $b|x-y|+\sigma |x-y|\leq |x-y|$ .

Prove that: $\mathbb E(X^x_t)^2\leq L \exp(Lt)$ for some none negative $L$ and for all $t > 0$.

If $X^n_t$ are by the Picard Iterations(Cause I have no other way of describing a solution), then their limit is a solution and each of them is measurable by the filtration.  I want to apply Doob's optional stopping time theorem on $\mathbb E(X^x_t)^2$ . For this I need a supermartingale and at least one of the boundary conditions in the theorem.

Editing further:

Now I have:

$\mathbb E\,[\sup\limits_{t\leq s}|X_{n}(s)-X_{n-1}(s)|^2] \leq$

$\leq T^2\mathbb E[|X_n(s)-X_{n-1}(s)|^2]+K\,T\,\mathbb E\,[|X_n(s)-X_{n-1}(s)|^2]$

And I think that my next step is applying some sort of inequality (Doob's/Jensen/etc..) But I'm not sure which one and how, any help?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: start off by looking at $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{s\leq t}|X_{s}|^{2}]$. You should be able to bound it above by a sum of three expectations involving the starting point, the contributions from the drift, and the Ito integral. In particular, the Ito integral part should look like $$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{s\leq t}\left|\int_{0}^{s}\sigma(X_{s},s)dW_{s}\right|^{2}\right].$$

Comment: why 3 expectations? I can get 2 ones if I use linearity of the expectations to break it into the integral and the Ito integral, and how did you get the ^2   inside the expectation? @par

Comment: I said 3 because I was counting the $\mathbb{E}|x|^2$ term (your initial condition can be generalized to an L2-integrable random variable instead of a constant). As for breaking up the terms, recall that $$|a+b|^{2}\leq(2\max\{|a|,|b|\})^{2}\leq4|a|^{2}+4|b|^{2}.$$

Comment: Wait, are you asking about $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ or $(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$?

Comment: that's actually a good question, I assume $\mathbb E(X)^2$ otherwise wouldn't it be written $\mathbb E^2$ ?

Comment: @JonesY: Your comment does not unambiguously answer my concerns :-) I would guess $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

Comment: let's say it's the left one. Look at the edit I made to my question, can you help any further?

Comment: You might be a bit confused; I am not sure what the subscript $n$ are. I recommend reading through the proof on page 12 of http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~touzi/Fields-LN.pdf

Comment: I understand now. You are using the Picard iterates, though I am not sure why. The statement is asking you to prove the inequality for a solution $X$ of the SDE, so it is not necessary to consider the iterates (the iterates are useful for proving existence and uniqueness via a contraction mapping).

Comment: Cause I know nothing about the solution except how to write it with iterations?
with this method I was able to have a series of upper bounds, which I think they are all correct. But then I'm stuck, I think applying Doob's Inequality (for submartingales?) is a correct way to continue, but I'm not sure the difference is a submartingale and if so how to apply the inequality? @par

Comment: You should try reading the link I sent you to.

Comment: YaY I wasn't that far away. It's basically the same chain of bounds and Doob's inequality in the end. Now I just need to see if I can leave it in Picard's iterations or re type it. Thank you @Par. you have helped a lot.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If my answer was satisfactory, please consider upvoting and/or accepting. Perhaps (if it is a valuable exercise) you can also write out your proof here for future stack exchangers to benefit from.